# iOS, How to determine word length in a list of strings in plist using NSArray

Tags: ios

I have a plist that has some thousands of strings in it.

```
<plist version="1.0">
 <array>
 <string>Hello</string>
 <string>Guitar</string>    
 <string>Geronimo</string>
  ......
 </array>
</plist>
```

As you can see, each string is of some length.
I am loading the words in an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *theList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myplist" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

I now want to iterate through all of the strings in theList and determine the length of each word so I can categorize them according to string length.

New to this environment - I have tried several variations, but am probably not using the proper syntax. How do I do this with objective c?

Comment: with this:I resolved this on my own:I resolved this on my own:                        NSMutableArray *wLengthArray3;
    int size;
    tempWordStr = [self.wordArray objectAtIndex: n];                    size = [tempWordStr length];

Comment: NSString *tempWordStr;
         tempWordStr = [self.wordArray objectAtIndex: n];   
         size = [tempWordStr length];

Comment: Well, cool. You resolved this on your own (`Apr 15 at 21:11`) **after** I gave you the correct answer (`Apr 15 at 17:42`). Sweet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need a mutable array for that; an `NSArray` would be just fine.

```
for (NSString *string in theList)
{
    NSUInteger length = string.length;
}
```

Comment: Thank You.  I am using a mutable array as I do not know how many strings there will be.  (There are as little as 30 and as many as 250,000 or so)

Comment: Using an `NSArray` with `-initWithContentsOfFile:` is just fine. It will have the required size and you cannot change it **after** initializing it, which is just fine for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSString *str in theList) {
    unsigned int lengthOfStr = [str length]; 
}
```